# Get field value without having to use imports from superclass?

Tags: java, reflection

I am relatively new to Java programming. I need to get a field value using Reflection. My current code looks like this (where superclasses is a set of classes that extend `MySuperClass`):

```
for (Class<? extends MySuperClass> s : subclasses) {
    try {
        field = s.getDeclaredField("MY_FIELD");
        fieldValue = (String) field.get(null);
    } catch ...
```

My problem is, whenever I call field.get, I get an error because the class `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` was not found. Where does this come from? Well, `MySuperClass`imports it. I don't know why Java thinks it's necessary to have it, because the classes I want to get the `MY_FIELD` value from dont import it. Of course they extend `MySuperClass` (which is abstract, if that matters). So is there any way to ***only*** get the field value from a specific class, without being dependent on the Classes the super class uses? I don't need to instantiate a class or something, just need to get that value...

I hope I explained well enough what my problem here is and apologize for my yet small Java knowledge.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: An `import` statement doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't actually _pull_ anything in. If you're getting a `ClassNotFoundException`, then some class you've loaded/initialized requires it, not because of an `import`, but because it actually uses it.

Comment: A stack trace and a reproducible example would help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every class depends

- on all its superclasses, and on everything on which any of them depends;
- on all interfaces it implements, and on everything on which any of them depends;
- on all classes and interfaces that represent the types of its class, instance, or local variables, its methods' argument types, or its methods' return types; and
- on all classes and interfaces that represent type parameter bounds of any of the above types.

In order to examine a class's static variables, invoke its static methods,  or instantiate it, that class must first be loaded.  In order to load a class, all its dependencies must also be loaded.

Use of reflection does not get around any of the above, so the basic answer is no, there is no way to read the value of a class's static variable without loading its superclass's dependencies.